# VSC use Code Runner to run code with a makefile?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, makefile, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I’m taking a class where we are learning c, our professor told us to install bash in wsl and to use makefiles to run our code.

I often have small mistakes in my code the first time I run, so it is frustrating having to type:
$ make filename
$ ./filename

Especially because I’m dyslexic and often misspell my filename. I’m therefore looking for a faster way to execute my code using a makefile. Something like the extension code runner which I used before taking the class were all I had to do was hit ctrl + alt + n.

Comment: You don't have to use `make filename`, you can just run `make` with no argument and it will build the first target in the makefile by default (so just be sure the first target in the makefile builds or depends on the thing(s) you want to build).  In bash you can also use command-line completion: type the first character or two (enough to be unique) and press the TAB key and the shell will complete it for you.  I have no advice for using Visual Code.

Comment: you can put those commands in a script, and run that as a one-liner...? I'm all for less typing, but complaining about this much seems a bit excessive. Whatever shell you're using probably supports using the up arrow to scroll thru a list of previously-entered commands, so you can just <up up enter> to `make` and the same thing again to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a target to run your code:  Imagine this simple `Makefile`:

```
my_prog_objs = a.o b.o c.o
my_prog_args = a b c
my_prog_out  = my_prog.out

.PHONY: all clean run

all: my_prog
clean:
    rm -f my_prog $(my_prog_objs)

# THIS IS THE IMPORTANT TARGET, first builds the
# program, then runs it.
run: my_prog
    my_prog $(my_prog_args) >$(my_progs_out)

my_prog: $(my_prog_objs)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $($@_objs)
```

by using `make` you get everything built, but running `make run` you build everything and run `my_prog` with the arguments shown in the `Makefile` (`a b c`) and the output redirected to `my_prog.out`  and this will save a lot of typing if you need to test it.